# $http request inside an angular.forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently working on a application, here is my code :

```js
var arr = [];
var loadData = function ( data ) {
  angular.forEach(data, function ( value, key ) {
    getData( data.id )
      .then( function ( response ) {
        arr.push( 
          {
            test: response
          }
        );
      })    
      .catch ( function ( response ) {
      
      }
  });
  console.log(arr);
}
```

The first time the code is runned, arr is empty. Can someone tell me why and to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Its asynchronous. Your `.then`'s in each loop haven't returned with data when the `console.log` is ran. Before you ask don't try to make it synchronous.

Comment: First thing, `angular.forEach` is looping over nothing. The first argument should be an array. Also to get the final result of all calls, you'll have to use `$q.all()`. But until I know the structure of `data`, I can't give you a good answer of what the working code will look like.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how can I get my complete array outside the foreach ? I like to call a function with this complete array in argument ?

Comment: The argument data is an array

Comment: Have a look at `$q.all` as DerekMT12 says. Pass it an array of ajax calls. It's `.then` will resolve when all promises in the passed array do. Giving you an array of their results. `$http` returns promises.

Comment: I've tried this solution, but I've to store in my array 'arr' data from each request. So if I do $q.all([getData(data.id)].then(function(response){ ... }), I have to do a foreach again and store it in my array 'arr' ... and it still not work. Is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [];
var loadData = function ( data ) {
  var promises = [];
  angular.forEach(data, function ( value, key ) {
    promises.push(getData( data.id );
  });
  $q.all(promises)
    .then(function ( response ) {
      arr.push(
        {
           test: response  
        }   
      );
      console.log(arr);
    }  
}
```

Thanks to ste2425 and DerekMT12.